# Unable to create unique key constraint - Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2, unique-constraint

The full error message is:

```
Unable to create unique key constraint (aircraft_series_id, service_enum) on table aircraft_service: database column 'service_enum' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
```

My entity is specified as:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "aircraft_series_id", "service_enum" }) })
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AircraftService {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private Integer minimumQuantity;

  @NotNull
  private Integer maximumQuantity;

  @NotNull
  private Integer defaultQuantity;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private AircraftSeries aircraftSeries;

  @NotNull
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ServiceEnum serviceEnum;

}
```

If I comment out the `@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "aircraft_series_id", "service_enum" }) })` annotation then the columns are created and I can see the field names when opening the table under the SQL client.

```
service_enum
aircraft_series_id
```

For now I'm running the application against the H2 database.

Answer (score 0):

I could have the application running not throw an exception if the class is boasting the column annotations, as in:

```
@Column(name = "service_enum")

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "service_profile_id")
```

I don't see why this is the case, as by default, the column names are exactly the same, when attributed by the application itself.